# Finding Specific Generators of $\left(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Does there exist an element $y$ of the group $\left(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ such that both $y$ and $1-y$ are generators of $\left(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$?

Clearly, this is true when $2$ is a generator of $\left(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ as $y = 2^{-1} = 1-y$ does the trick. But I'm not sure how to prove that there is such an element when $2$ is not a generator of $\left(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$.

Comment: This follows for $p > 61$ by taking $a=b=c=1$ in Theorem 1 of the paper by Cohen, Oliveira e Silva and Trudgian at [arxiv.org/abs/1402.2724](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2724).  For $p \le 61$, it is easily checked directly.

Comment: @FredH, this looks like an answer.

Comment: thanks @FredH for a very elegant answer. Indeed theorem 1 gives a much more general answer to the question that I asked